# Meteor Autoform settings outside of the main Schema File

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor, schema

I'm working on several content schemas that handle validation, but if possible prefer not to define autoform properties in that schema aswell. I'd rather keep the schema files clean with just what is required.

Ideally Id like an autoform and a schema file for each collection.  whats the best practice for this?  is there one?   I took a look at the code and it looks like the best option is to create a simple schema object for each and attach them both via collection 2?

any thoughts out there?
thanks in advance.
JK